# Why can't apply be used with classList?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to add to an element's `classList` in an environment where I don't have the spread syntax available. Using `apply` is failing with a TypeError:

```js
const classes = 'red blue';
const tag = document.querySelector('#tag')
const list =  classes.split(/\s/);
console.log(list); // ['red', 'blue']
tag.classList.add.apply(tag, list); // Error
tag.classList.add('green'); // doesn't happen
```

```css
.blue {
  background: blue
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  border: 3px double green;
}
```

```html
<p id="tag">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nam nihil sed, dicta, maxime, atque nulla voluptatibus necessitatibus aliquam quasi inventore voluptas dolore labore ratione officia! Rerum vel, similique perferendis?</p>
```

> `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

I must be doing something incorrectly, because this works with spread. What's the problem with this invocation of `classList.add`?

Comment: You're passing `tag` as the `this` to use. You should be passing `tag.classList`: `tag.classList.add.apply(tag.classList, list)` But since you're using ES2015+ features anyway, just use spread notation: `tag.classList.add(...list);`

Comment: ^^ given the above, I'm voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. Just a simple mistake. :-)

Comment: *(Of **course** I also got it wrong in my comment, now fixed.)*

Answer (score -1):

Docs for [Function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> The apply() method calls a function with a given `this` value, and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).

A natural question arises. What is `this` by default? This is where your misunderstanding stems.

Docs for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Take this snippet for instance. It will create an object with a member method and put that object inside an outer object. What does it output?

```js
innerObj = 
{
  a: "inner",
  func: function() {
    return this.a;
  },
};

outerObj = {
  a: "outer",
  inner : innerObj
};

console.log(outerObj.inner.func())
```

This shows that `this` by default will be the innermost object. In your case, the code

```
tag.classList.add('green');
```

will use the innermost object (a.k.a. `classList`) as `this`. You applied the outer object `tag` as `this` and that's why you get a TypeError.

Hope this is clear

Comment: The question is basically a typo. Typos don't need *answers*, just comments if no  one's made the comment (I have) and close votes (when you have the rep).

Comment: The typo is a different problem all together. It is clear that even if the typo was fixed, the question wouldn't be solved. This is a question boiling down to how functions determine what `this` is when a function is invoked. I would argue this is a valid question

Answer (score -2):

You should use **t** instead of **tag**

```
const classes = 'red blue';
const t = document.querySelector('#tag')
const list =  classes.split(/\s/);

t.classList.add.apply(t, list);
```

Comment: I’m sorry, why?

Comment: he declares a variable t which receives the paragraph element

Comment: Ah, I see now. Good catch! Thanks :-)